# Interpretation of significant predictors in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, chi-squared-test, interpretation

I am approaching an exercise about data analysis, but I have some doubts about interpreting my results.

I have $p$ predictors, some categorical, others continuous (let's call them $X_1$, $X_2$, $\dots$ ,$X_p$) and one response variable $Y$, which is dichotomous.
I applied logistic regression and found that among $p$ predictors, $m$ predictors are significant, with $m < p$.
On the other hand, performing a Pearson's Chi-squared test between $Y$ and a categorical predictor among the $m$ significant predictors in the regression analysis, I find that there is no association between the two variables.

I was wondering how this fact can be correctly interpreted.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Two possibilities:  Either the effects are confounded or the effect of the predictors relative to the remaining variance in the outcome is too small.  I would encourage you NOT to ever do a bi-variable analysis of outcome and predictor in this manner because it can obfuscate effects (because of confounding).

Comment: @DemetriPananos many thanks! can you please explain why you suggest me not to do a bi-variable analysis? (I mean, I see the problem of confounding, but I want to understand if it is always wrong to do a bivariate test when you have many predictors).